# Translation animation flickering

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm experiencing the following problem with animations in Android: I want to animate some boats moving from right to left in and out of the screen. These boats have text written on them and these texts have to move along with the boats. What I implemented is a layout with 4 boats and animate them 1 length to the left with a translate animation and then repeat this animation. The boat in the center has a certain text written on it and the boat to the right has the second text, so the user can see it as the boat moves into the screen. However, when the animation repeats itself, the text from the right boat is drawn on the new center boat, which causes a flickering effect while the boat animation looks fine. Please see the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYtsJazta84) for an example. This video was recorded from the emulator and it exaggerates the problem a bit, on actual devices it's more of a flickering effect.

I've tried several possible solutions found on SO, such as `.setFillAfter(true)` and delaying the drawing of the next repetition, but none of this solves the problem. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?